# MCP1755S regulator and output voltage

Tags: batteries, atmega, ldo, 3.3v

With a homemade PCB, I've built my own Arduino-inspired controller, with an ATmega328P flashed in a way to work @3.3 V. I power the whole thing with a battery@ 7.4 V.

I use the [LDO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-dropout_regulator) [MCP1755S](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/25160A.pdf) (with 3.3 V of output voltage).

It really doesn't work. The LDO outputs something between 1.9 and 2.6 V, making the ATmega really unstable (it didn't even pass the serial welcome [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/printf)).

If I make a measurement at the output of the regulator, plugged to the battery in input, I've more or less 4 V. With just an LED and a 330 Ω resistor, I get the 3.3 V.

It seems like this LDO doesn't like my circuit, but it doesn't take more than 50 mA, so I in the capacity of the LDO.

Between the ground and the VOUT I've two 22 µF capacitors to stabilize the voltage across the circuit (I use an NRF24L01 RF module, and it's really sensitive to voltage stability).

I've tried to remove the two 22 µF capacitors, and I've replaced them with a 1 µF X7R ceramic capacitor (input capacitor). Just changing that and I was able to upload code to my Arduino-bootloaded ATmega328P, and it was booting and sending a serial message. The output voltage was between 2.8 and 3.2 V. I've put a 1 µF capacitor on the input side (input capacitor) and voltage is now stable at 3.3 V. Already a good progression!

But if I plug anything into my PCB ([RFID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification) reader, RF module, etc.) then it stucks and doesn't boot again.

Here's the PCB we've designed (stab Vreg2 being the input capacitor, stab RF2 is removed and replaced by a through-hole wire to link both PCB sides):

[image: PCB inspired by bareduino]

What's going wrong? With another LDO I don't get the trouble.

Comment: What is the ESR of your capacitors?

Comment: It's pretty difficult to make guesses without more information of the circuit. Can you add a schematic to the post?

Comment: I think that the capacitor ESR is part of the trouble. I didn't know that capacitor could have such a big impact on the LDO. The datasheet give a typical application with 1uF output capa. I've 44uF!

Comment: I've tried to adapt capacitors as suggested by @ThePhoton and edited the question. Thank you!

Comment: Check that the current is below 50mA - I have a suspicion that it isn't and is causing the regulator to thermally shut down.

Comment: But the regulator admit 300mA of output no? And it seems like that will cause the voltage to dropdown seriously, but my voltmeter continue to display 3.3v

Comment: The output capacitor must have an ESR < 2 ohms. What specific capacitor are you using? An ESR outside of the prescribed range can cause oscillation of the part.

Comment: I use this cap:http://be.farnell.com/fr-BE/multicomp/mcmlr50v105kx7r/cap-cer-x7r-1uf-50v-rad/dp/2112947

Comment: But ESR is not specified :-( Btw, it seems that ceramic have the lower ESR

Comment: The ESR requirement lists only a maximum (interesting as the pass element is P-channel). A ceramic should be well below the listed maximum, so it is unlikely to be this, but the 1uF is listed as a minimum. Try adding a second device in parallel in case the part you have happens to be low capacitance.

Comment: Thank you @PeterSmith. By device you mean the 1uF? And by part what do you mean?

Comment: I would suggest adding a second capacitor of 1uF on the output just in case the regulator is unstable with a single output capacitor, which it may be if the existing output capacitor is below its nominal value.

Comment: Yes! My RFID works now. Trying to send from the RF module still re-init the entire program. I've no more room for additional capacitor on my pcb... I'll order higher capacitor and we'll see. Thank you for precious advice!

Comment: One more thing: it was still a bit instable(1/10 of working probability), so i've added input capacitors and now it seems to work more (1/2). But it's not yet perfect.

Answer (score 2):

This family of LDOs is highly sensitive to output and input capacitance. Low [ESR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_series_resistance) is mandatory.

Changing for ceramic capacitors makes it work a lot better (my ATmega initializes and accepts code upload). There remains many ways to improve stability, according to the document *[AN765 - Using Microchip's Micropower LDOs](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00765a.pdf)*:

> However, the ESR of ceramic capacitors sometimes can be too low, requiring a 1 Ω series resistor to ensure stability.

I'll order a resistor.